# Databricks Delta Table from Datalake with Partitioned Folders

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, delta-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have data on Azure Storage Account in a Container called Staging.

Using the SourceSystem/Dataset hierarchy I also have date based folder per month.
[image]
Inside the folder the data is stored in a delta format.
[image]

In data bricks I already have the the container mounted.
I want to create a Delta Table whereby I can see ALL the data in the underlying folder printtransaction folder.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS staging.default.ysoft_printtransaction;

CREATE TABLE staging.default.ysoft_printtransaction
USING delta
OPTIONS ('delta.checkpoint.writeStatsAsJson' 'false', 'delta.checkpoint.writeStatsAsStruct' 'true')
LOCATION 'abfss://staging@saccdssanpoc01.dfs.core.windows.net/ysoft/printtransaction/*/';

SELECT * FROM staging.default.ysoft_printtransaction;
```

This however does not work as I am getting an issue when reading from the table stating:
[image]

Obviously I don't want to create a table per partitioned folder.

What are my options?

Comment: Each folder is already a Delta Lake table. Do you want to combine them all together? Who wrote that tables? It's really not a best design

Comment: I realise they are. I would prefer to not have the underlying deltas under the SourceSystem\Dataset. Each dataset have a dedicated column called _partition which I can use to rather create a single delta table with a partition reference.

Comment: Yep, read each table separately, and output it somewhere else as a single table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per information you provided these two folders are separate delta table. I agree with @Alex Ott as he said as these two folders are separate delta tables you need to read them separately then you can merge them and combine it using merge query in the different table.

It will not be able read the data from multiple delta tables in a single table.

[image]

**Sample code to read each folder separately:**

```sql
CREATE  TABLE  ysoft_printtransaction1
USING delta
Location  'abfss://containername@storageaccname.dfs.core.windows.net/sampledb/202113';

CREATE  TABLE  ysoft_printtransaction2
USING delta
Location  'abfss://containername@storageaccname.dfs.core.windows.net/sampledb/202110';
```

To merge table, you can use following command.

```sql
MERGE  INTO  target  USING  source
  ON  target.key  =  source.key
  WHEN  NOT  MATCHED  THEN  INSERT  *
```